# HTML radio button naming for multiple groups

Tags: php, layout, radio-button, grouping, naming

I am developing a PHP website which will generate several approval requests.

My approval page has only one form and one save button, and I want to use 2 radio buttons for each request.

Here is a link to how I imagine it to look like: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cEMpB/2/)

On the PHP side I have no problem with generating the form and assigning different names to the radio buttons. My problem is what names I should give to the radio buttons in order for me to be able to associate them to a specific member on the PHP side? Or do I need to set values for the radio buttons?

How would I accomplish this?

If you have an even better solution to handle such a case I am open to that as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every User will have a unique user_id,
As you are displaying radiobuttongroup for each other user in the page, and want to access then in php,
The base way to name them in a array with indices as their user_id

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="acceptance['uid1']"/>Approve<br />
<input type="radio" value="0" name="acceptance[uid1]"/>Deny

<input type="radio" value="1" name="acceptance['uid2']"/>Approve<br />
<input type="radio" value="0" name="acceptance[uid2]"/>Deny

<input type="radio" value="1" name="acceptance['uid3']"/>Approve<br />
<input type="radio" value="0" name="acceptance[uid3]"/>Deny
```

in php

```
foreach($_POST['acceptence'] as $uid=>$acpt)
{
..Do whatever
}
```

I hope this would help..If something else is needed plz comment..

Comment: This is already very close to what i want. Only one more thing to sort out: There could be several requests of the same user on the page. i.e. one request to access the forum another to become an administrator.

Comment: In that case make separate arrays for separate purposes... that is: for request to acces: access_acceptance[uid], request to become admin: admin_acceptance[uid]..etc..etc...I php make separate foreach loops for separate arrays...that way it will be much easy for further data manuplation also...Lemme noe if smthng more required..otherwise Plz accept the answer if you think its resolved

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
<input type="radio" value="approve" name="acceptance"/>Approve<br />
<input type="radio" value="deny" name="acceptance"/>Deny
```

With radio buttons, they should named the same and have different values for grouping them.

UPDATED

To me, I will add row id to each radio group buttons. For example

```
<input type="radio" value="19" name="acceptance1"/>Approve<br />
<input type="radio" value="0" name="acceptance1"/>Deny
...
<input type="radio" value="21" name="acceptance2"/>Approve<br />
<input type="radio" value="0" name="acceptance2"/>Deny
...
<input type="radio" value="23" name="acceptance5"/>Approve<br />
<input type="radio" value="0" name="acceptance5"/>Deny
```

Assuming we have 5 rows per page and each approve radio button holds id of a records in database.

```
<?php
    $approve = array();
    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
        $approve[] = $_POST['acceptance'.$i];
?>
```

Then you will get what row has approve selection (i.e value !=0). Hope this helps

Comment: But how can I link this to a specific member on the php side, when i have several of these on the page? I need to include the member ID somehow for each request.

Comment: If they have the same name, you can only select one at a time, and when you submit the form (e.g via POST), $_POST['acceptance'] will return only one value.

Comment: Ok. But that is exactly the problem. I need several radio button groups.

Comment: @MichaelFrey Let's I think, but to me change to check boxes is easier.